VBA - Word add a ComboBox and fill it with values
I dont understand why I cant just simply add an ActiveX ComboBox to Word and fill values via VBA... Word is just weird in comparism to Excel.
When I add the ComboBox called ComboBox1 and open the code I get this auto generated:
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub

Now I created something like this:
Private Sub FillComboBox()

    Dim cb As comboBox
    Set cb = ThisDocument.Forms("ThisDocument").Controls("ComboBox1")

     'Clear the ComboBox first
    cb.Clear

     'Add items to the ComboBox
    cb.AddItem "Option 1"
    cb.AddItem "Option 2"
    cb.AddItem "Option 3"
    cb.AddItem "Option 4"

End Sub


Private Sub Document_Open()
    FillComboBox
End Sub

And also tried to call FillComboBox in the change event but it either yields an error or simply does nothing.. I also tried to use MyDocument and ActiveDocument but it simply does not work.
Thanks

In Word you can create a reference to an ActiveX control simply with its name Set cb = ThisDocument.ComboBox1

When I use this it still does not fill the values and does not work

To create an ActiveX ComboBox

Right click the Ribbon and choose Customize Ribbon
Choose Commands from: Commands Not in the Ribbon
On the right pane click Create a New Tab then Rename and type ActiveX click OK
On the left pane select ComboBox (ActiveX Control) and click Add
Close with OK

then add a combobox from the newly created Tab to the document. Change the assignment like this. (To get the name of the inserted combobox select it and get it from the Properties window.)
Set cb = ThisDocument.ComboBox1

The result looks like this:

